# Search in JSON with Postgres without knowing all keys

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to search in a JSON using Postgres. The JSON looks like that:

```
  "some key": {
    "city": "Chicago",
    "id": "",
    "color": "",
    "size": ""
  },
  "a different key": {
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "id": null,
    "shape": "",
    "height": ""
  }
```

I don't know what can the names of the first level keys (that's why I called them "some key" and "a different key" in the example above). I do know that they can be different from one another.

I want to extract all the values of the "city" key, Chicago and San Francisco in the example above.
I guess it's something like that but this one didn't work:

```
(table_name.row_name-> * ->> 'city') as city_name
```

(I know that the city is always in the second level on the JSON, but can occur multiple times)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys:

```
select t.some_column, 
       x.item -> 'city' as city_name
from the_table t
   cross join jsonb_each(t.the_column) as x(item)
```

This returns each city as a new row together with the other columns of that table.

The above assumes your column is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it isn't you need to use `json_each()` instead